# Function returning undefined after calling in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I'm trying to make a shopping cart using JS and one of my tasks is to create a placeOrder function.

- The placeOrder() function accepts one argument, a credit card number.
- If no argument is received, the function should print out Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you.
- If a card number is received, the function should print out `Your total cost is $71, which will be charged to the card 83296759`.  Then, it should empty the cart array.

However, when I call in the total function into the string keeps returning undefined.

```js
var cart = [];

function getCart() {
  return cart;
}

function setCart(c) {
  cart = c;
  return cart;
}

function addToCart(itemName) {
  var object = {
    [itemName]: Math.floor(Math.random(1, 100) * 100)
  };
  cart.push(object);
  console.log(`${itemName} has been added to your cart`);
  return cart;
}

function total() {
  if (cart.length !== 0) {
    var totalValue = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      for (var item in cart[i]) {
        totalValue.push(cart[i][item]);
        var sum = totalValue.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }, 0);
        console.log(`The total value is ${sum}`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    return ("Your shopping cart is empty.")
  }
}

function placeOrder(cardNumber) {
  if (cardNumber === undefined) {
    return ("Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you.");
  } else {
    console.log(`Your total cost is $${total()}, which will be charged to the card ${cardNumber}`);
    cart = [];
    return cart;
  }
}

addToCart("a");
addToCart("be");
addToCart("cart");
placeOrder(14564);
```

Output:

```
Your total cost is $undefined, which will be charged to the card 14564
```

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything if the cart isn't empty. `console.log` ≠ `return`. You should use `console.log` as little as possible, except when debugging.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev There isn't any, I added all the ones I called.

Comment: @Carcigenicate my bad, I'll rephrase the question, however, I have tried using return and got the same output

Comment: @Rookie Just return `sum` from `total`. Im not sure what you tried, but that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no return of the function total when cart.length != 0.
You have to return sum.

```
if (cart.length !== 0) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< cart.length; i++) {
      for(var item in cart[i]) {
        totalValue.push(cart[i][item]);
        sum = totalValue.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;}, 0);
        console.log(`The total value is ${sum}`);    
      }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Carcigenicate said, you should call return something at the end of your if(cart.length !== 0) {} statment. Remember that when return is called, the function stops it's exectution immediatly, with no evaluation of the further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure `total` always returns a `number`, e.g.:

```js
var cart = [{
    "a": 86
  },
  {
    "be": 2
  },
  {
    "cart": 24
  }
];

function total(cart) {
  return cart
    .reduce(function(prices, item) {
      return prices.concat(Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]));
    }, [])
    .reduce(function(sum, price) {
      return sum += price;
    }, 0);
}

console.log(total([]));
console.log(total(cart));
```

The usage in `placeOrder` might look like this then:

```js
function total(cart) {
  return cart
    .reduce(function(prices, item) {
      return prices.concat(Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]));
    }, [])
    .reduce(function(sum, price) {
      return sum += price;
    }, 0);
}

function placeOrder(cardNumber, cart) {
  if (cardNumber === undefined) {
    return "Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you.";
  }

  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return "You cart is empty";
  }

  return `Your total cost is $${total(cart)}, which will be charged to the card ${cardNumber}`;
  return [];
}

console.log(placeOrder(1234, []));
console.log(placeOrder(1234, [{
  a: 1
}, {
  b: 2
}]));
```

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know what's the purpose of that array `totalValue` but you don't need that function `reduce`, just loop over items and sum the amounts.
- You're looping through the values of each item, get the amount of your items directly using `Object.values(cart[i]).pop();`.

---

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  var amount = Object.values(cart[i]).pop();
  sum += amount;        
}
```

Finally, return that `sum`.

```js
var cart = [];

function getCart() {
  return cart;
}

function setCart(c) {
  cart = c;
  return cart;
}

function addToCart(itemName) {
  var object = {
    [itemName]: Math.floor(Math.random(1, 100) * 100)
  };
  cart.push(object);
  console.log(`${itemName} has been added to your cart`);
  return cart;
}

function total() {
  if (cart.length !== 0) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      for (var item in cart[i]) {
        sum += cart[i][item];        
      }
    }
    console.log(`The total value is ${sum}`);
    
    return sum;
  }
  
  return -1; // Could be 0, this is up to you.
}

function placeOrder(cardNumber) {
  if (cardNumber === undefined) {
    return ("Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you.");
  } else {
  
    var sum = total();
    if (sum) {
    console.log(`Your total cost is $${sum}, which will be charged to the card ${cardNumber}`);
    } else {
      console.log("Your shopping cart is empty.")
    }
    cart = [];
    return cart;
  }
}

addToCart("a");
addToCart("be");
addToCart("cart");
placeOrder(14564);
```